# Add an "outdated version" custom close reason

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

Related to: [Close Question For Being Too Old?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/close-question-for-being-too-old)

Let's add a custom close reason for questions on an outdated version of the Salesforce platform!  (Not a question that is based on old-but-accessible APIs or Apex, but specifically things that are no longer accessible, like tips for getting around the lines-of-code limit).

What should it say?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

> This unanswered question refers to an outdated and unavailable version of the Salesforce platform. The issues raised here are no longer relevant.

I would also suggest only closing unanswered or poorly-answered questions like this.

Comment: Except, to some extent, most of the old API versions are available. Still, that doesn't mean you can always reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Agreed - questions about Apex, VF, metadata and APIs would not be subject to this.